# Accessing customizer values in javascript

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I'm using a page builder (Divi) and have made several custom controls for the Theme Customizer. No problems hooking up the live preview using postMessage. The issue is that I want to change the content of the DOM using jQuery based on what is selected in the Customizer. Because I'm using a page builder I'm not writing php in the page template to utilize get_theme_mod(). Is there another way to access the controls values on the client side with javascript? 
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917798/data-not-passing-correctly-with-wp-localize-script Check this answer for how to use wp_localize_script() to pass an array of variables to your javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Given a setting with an ID of “foo” you can obtain the value via:

```
var value = wp.customize( 'foo' ).get()
```

To ensure that the setting is registered before you attempt to get its value, you can use this deferred pattern:

```
wp.customize( 'foo', function( setting ) {
    var value = setting.get();
    // ...
});
```

This should look familiar because these calls are very common in JS that gets enqueued in the Customizer preview for handling setting change previews via `postMessage`.

Comment: I keep getting 'wp.customize is not a function'. I am enqueueing my script in the footer of my page. It seems like I can only make calls to the wp.customize method if the customizer is open?

Comment: @RobertMeans Right, the `wp.customize` object is normally only enqueued in the Customizer.

Comment: So, what do you think the best approach would be to access those variables in javascript? I'm thinking of passing them through get_theme_mod in my functions.php and using wp_localize to pass the values over. I'm just not sure about when the controls are saved.

Comment: It's hard to know since I don't use Divi and there aren't a lot of details (e.g. code) in your question.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Thanks